# How to install fio 3.13 on ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: 18.04

The current version of fio supported on Ubuntu 18.04.2 is 2.12, I need fio 3.13 to perform buffer related I/O operations.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 3.13 for Ubuntu yet.

- [3.8 is cosmic/18.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/fio)
- [3.12 is disco/19.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/fio)
- alternative debian 10  has 3.12 too.

So if you want it from a debian installer you need to wait for 19.10.

The only way is installation from a [source file](https://archlinux.pkgs.org/rolling/archlinux-community-x86_64/fio-3.13-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz.html). [Download is to an arch ftp for 3.13.](https://ftp.fau.de/archlinux/community/os/x86_64/)

Comment: It's actually fairly [easy to build fio from source on Ubuntu when you have its dependencies installed](https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/fio-3.13/README#L132).